# increment of two in ngFor , Angular5

Tags: angularjs, angular

I m having a piece of code in Angular 5 with ngFor as shown below

**Angular Model**

```
 export class UserReviews {
  public PageName: string;
  public UserName: string;
  public Review: string;
  public Rating: number;
  public IsApproved: boolean;
}
```

**Varibales**

```
UserReviewModel: UserReviews = new UserReviews();
UserReviewList: UserReviews[] = [];
this.UserReviewList = [
      {
        PageName: "Page Name Here",UserName: "User1",Review:"Review Here",
        Rating: 3,IsApproved: true
      },
      {
        PageName: "Page Name Here",UserName: "User2",Review:"Review Here",
        Rating: 4,IsApproved: true
      },
      {
        PageName: "Page Name Here",UserName: "User3",Review:"Review Here",
        Rating: 3, IsApproved: true
      },
      {
        PageName: "Page Name Here",UserName: "User4",Review:"Review Here",
        Rating: 2,IsApproved: true
      },
      {
        PageName: "Page Name Here",UserName: "User5",Review:"Review Here",
        Rating: 3,IsApproved: true
      },
      {
        PageName: "Page Name Here",UserName: "User6",Review:"Review Here",
        Rating: 4,IsApproved: true
      },
      {
        PageName: "Page Name Here",UserName: "User7",Review:"Review Here",
        Rating: 4,IsApproved: true
      },
      {
        PageName: "Page Name Here",UserName: "User8",Review:"Review Here",
        Rating: 5,IsApproved: true
      }
    ];
```

**HTML Template**

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let item of UserReviewList;let i = index">
    <div class="col-md-6 border-right-0">
      <div class="mb-1 text-grey">{{UserReviewList[i].UserName}}</div>
      <div class="mb-1">
        <i class="fas fa-star text-warning"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-star text-warning"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-star text-warning"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-star text-warning"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-star-half-alt text-warning"></i>
        <strong class="ml-1">{{UserReviewList[i].Rating}}</strong>
      </div>
      <div class="mb-1">
        {{UserReviewList[i].Review}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="mb-1 text-grey">{{UserReviewList[i+1].UserName}}</div>
      <div class="mb-1">
        <i class="fas fa-star text-warning"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-star text-warning"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-star text-warning"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-star text-warning"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-star-half-alt text-warning"></i>
        <strong class="ml-1">{{UserReviewList[i].Rating}}</strong>
      </div>
      <div class="mb-1">
          {{UserReviewList[i].Review}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

What i am trying to achieve here is to display reviews in row but in one row there should be two review
Example : row 1 should have review 1 and 2, same row 2 have review 3 and 4

**But problem is** that it is showing review 1 and 2 in row 1 and row 2 it is showing review 2 and 3 instead on 3 and 4 so 2(even index item) is getting repeat again

You can have an idea of this from below image

[image]

AS shown here in second here , it should start with user 3 instead of user 4 and so on in 3rd row user 5 and user 6

My idea to achieve this is to increment i by 2 in ngFor

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let item of UserReviewList;let i = index">
```

> In let i =index ; i++=2

But seems like it is not allowed in angular ,

How can i achieve this in **angular** and also in **angularjs ng repeat** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding only

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 border-right-0" *ngFor="let item of UserReviewList;let i = index">
            <div class="mb-1 text-grey">{{UserReviewList[i].UserName}}</div>
            <div class="mb-1">
                   <i class="fas fa-star text-warning"></i>
                   <i class="fas fa-star text-warning"></i>
                   <i class="fas fa-star text-warning"></i>
                   <i class="fas fa-star text-warning"></i>
                   <i class="fas fa-star-half-alt text-warning"></i>
                   <strong class="ml-1">{{UserReviewList[i].Rating}}</strong>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-1">
                  {{UserReviewList[i].Review}}
            </div>
       </div>
```

I think no need to add second div

Comment: Exactly what i did just few seconds ago , thanks by the way . My code was overkill here .

Answer (score 5):

Better way to achieve solution is by writing your styles in a way that your content should dynamically get assigned to the position required and **NOT** by skipping an index in ngFor.